# Aligning text inside tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a table with one column being dates, then other column something about the dates:

```
\documentclass[margin,line,pifont,palatino,courier]{res}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[latin1] { inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}

...

\begin{resume}
...
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1.2in}p{3.7in}}
01 / 10 - 28 / 1980 & On this day.\\
\vskip2pt\\
05 / 20 / 1982 & Text \\
\vskip2pt\\
12 / 13 - 31 / 2013&  Text \\
\end{tabular}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

How can I align the `/` in the first column?

Edit: What I mean is that I have two columns. In the first column the forward slashes are not aligned under each other. I would like to have them aligned under each other.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for updating your code to provide an example where the second set of forward slashes doesn't line up. One way to fix this is to make `/` be part of the intercolumn space, as is done in the following example, where the slashes are bordered `1pt` of whitespace on either side:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin,line,pifont,palatino,courier]{res}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}

...

\begin{resume}
...

\begin{tabular}{@{} r @{\kern1pt/\kern1pt} r @{\kern1pt/\kern1pt} l p{3.7in}}
01 & 10--28 & 1980 & On this day.\\[2pt]
05 & 20     & 1982 & Text        \\[2pt]
12 & 13--31 & 2013 & Text        \\
\end{tabular}
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

If you would prefer to have the day data centered rather than flush-right, just change the second `r` to `c`. By the way, I would use an "en-dash" (created with `--`) rather than a simple dash (`-`) as the days-of-the-month connector.